# Error in calling function

Tags: c, function

While compiling this code in the terminal, I am getting an error saying  :

```
newfile1.c:17: error: conflicting types for ‘average’
newfile1.c:2: note: previous declaration of ‘average’ was here
```

I don't see what is wrong with the code. Could someone help me out?

```
enter code here
#include<stdio.h>
float average(float);
int main()
{
        float marks[4],avg;
        int i;
        printf("Please enter your marks\n");
        for(i=0;i<=3;i++)
        {
                scanf("%d",&marks[i]);
        }
        avg = average(marks[4]);
        printf("The average marks value is %f",avg);
        return 0;
}



float average(float a[4])
{
       int i,sum;
       float avg_m;
       for(i=0;i<=3;i++)
       {
               sum=sum+a[i];
       }
       avg_m=sum/3;
       return avg_m;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Replace

```
float average(float);
```

with

```
float average(float[]);
```

The function declaration and definition are not matching.

Then call the function like this:

`avg = average(marks);`

Comment: I did that, and got two more errors:
newfile1.c:12: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘average’
newfile1.c:2: note: expected ‘float *’ but argument is of type ‘float’

Answer (score 2):

Change line in your file

```
float average(float);
```

to

```
float average(float []);
```

You have declared the function to take one `float` instead you want array of `floats`.

Also, while calling it in `main`, change to

```
avg = average(marks);
```

Comment: Okay, thanks! But, why did you remove the parentheses for marks? Don't we want it to take the array marks as input and use it?

Comment: @SamyuktaRamnath, `marks` will give you starting address of array, while `marks[4]` will give you 5th element in array, which is not is required.

Answer (score 1):

```
float average(float);
```

expects a float variable . You need to pass an array , so add
 `float average(float[]);`. Error happened since your function declaration and definition not matching.

in your main, you should call `avg = average(marks);` to pass the array to function `avg = average(marks[4]);` will pass a single variable.

Answer (score 1):

In the prototype of `average`, you have given `float` as argument type so compiler is expecting a single float value as argument. If you want to pass an array of values, you have to declare your prototype like this:

```
float average(float input_marks[]);
```

You can't give length of an array argument in a prototype or definition. You have to pass array length as a separate argument. So your prototype should look something like

```
float average(float a[], int a_length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `average` takes *one* `float` as argument, hence the declaration should be `floa avaerage(float)`. If you do `float average(float a[4])` you are telling compiler that your function takes an array of 4 floats as argument.